# In my test program, why can't cv::resize can’t execute while cvtColor can?

Tags: c++, opencv

My test program compiles. But when it executes `cv::resize`,  the operation can't be completed.

My code is below：

```
Mat gray,smallImg(cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1);
resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0,0, INTER_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Please provide a understandable code so that anyone can replicate that and try to find the solution.

Comment: your src is `gray` which is empty

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
Mat gray,
```

You have declared the cv::Mat `gray` but haven't initialized it with an image before calling `resize` on it. Please try loading an image there first.